# Get ID from url for sql request in DAO JEE project

Tags: java, sql, servlets, jakarta-ee, dao

I'm here today because I have a problem. 
I'm trying to use the DAO concept for my app in JEE.

The problem is that using DAO concept is much more difficult for me.

I tried to display a list of "sites".
Displaying the list was okay and worked fine.

But now, I want to display the same list with one parameter which is in the url.

For example, my url is : http://localhost:8080/secteurs?ID=3

My servlet looks like this :

```
package org.oc.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.oc.beans.InfoSecteur;
import org.oc.beans.InfoSite;
import org.oc.dao.*;

public class Secteur extends HttpServlet {

private InfoSecteurDao infoSecteurDao;

public void init() throws ServletException {
    DaoFactory daoFactory = DaoFactory.getInstance();
    this.infoSecteurDao = daoFactory.getInfoSecteurDao();

}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws
        ServletException, IOException {

    int site_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("ID"));
    request.setAttribute("site_id", site_id);
    request.setAttribute("infoSecteurs", infoSecteurDao.lister(site_id));
    this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/secteurs.jsp").forward(request, response);
}


public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    InfoSecteur infoSecteur = new InfoSecteur();
    infoSecteur.setName(request.getParameter("name"));
    infoSecteur.setSite_id(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("site_id")));
    infoSecteur.setDescription(request.getParameter("description"));

    infoSecteurDao.ajouter(infoSecteur);
    String site_id = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("site_id")));
    request.setAttribute("site_id", site_id);
    request.setAttribute("infoSecteurs", infoSecteurDao.lister(Integer.parseInt(site_id)));
    this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/secteurs.jsp").forward(request, response);

}

}
```

My DAO Impl looks like this:

```
package org.oc.dao;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import org.oc.beans.InfoSecteur;


public class InfoSecteurDaoImpl implements InfoSecteurDao {
    private DaoFactory daoFactory;

InfoSecteurDaoImpl(DaoFactory daoFactory) {
    this.daoFactory = daoFactory;
}

@Override
public void ajouter(InfoSecteur infoSecteur) {
    Connection connexion = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

    try {
        connexion = daoFactory.getConnection();

        preparedStatement = connexion.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO sector( name, description, site_id) VALUES(?, ?, ?);");
        preparedStatement.setString(1, infoSecteur.getName());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, infoSecteur.getDescription());
        preparedStatement.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(infoSecteur.getSite_id())));

        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public List<InfoSecteur> lister(int siteID) {
    List<InfoSecteur> infoSecteurs = new ArrayList<InfoSecteur>();
    Connection connexion = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet resultat = null;

    try {
        connexion = daoFactory.getConnection();
        ps = connexion.prepareStatement("SELECT name, description, site_id FROM sector WHERE site_id=?");
        ps.setString(1, String.valueOf(siteID));

        while (resultat.next()) {

            String name = resultat.getString("name");
            String description = resultat.getString("description");
            int site_id = resultat.getInt("site_id");


            InfoSecteur infoSecteur = new InfoSecteur();
            infoSecteur.setName(name);
            infoSecteur.setDescription(description);
            infoSecteur.setSite_id(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(site_id)));


            infoSecteurs.add(infoSecteur);

        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } return infoSecteurs;

}


}
```

I only need ONE THING, get the parameter id=3 of the url, and put it on my sql query select, to get only the site where the site_id=3 in DB. 
Please, don't send me to a tuto or another answer here, I spend almost 2 days trying to figure it out, and I didn't success.

Thanks a lot !

I have this error :

```
exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
org.oc.dao.InfoSecteurDaoImpl.lister(InfoSecteurDaoImpl.java:54)
org.oc.servlets.Secteur.doGet(Secteur.java:42)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your information, this is the code I used to solve my problem (sorry, the comments are in french, but you can easily understand only with the code) :

```
public void ajouter(InfoSecteur infoSecteur) {
    Connection connexion = null;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

    try {
        connexion = daoFactory.getConnection();
        //On récupère l'objet daoFactory.getConnection(), qui représente la connexion,
        // Ainsi on n'a pas besoin de refaire la connexion systématiquement
        // On récupère la connexion qui a déjà été faite en amont dans la factory
        preparedStatement = connexion.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO sector( name, description, site_id) VALUES(?, ?, ?);");
        preparedStatement.setString(1, infoSecteur.getName());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, infoSecteur.getDescription());
        preparedStatement.setInt(3, infoSecteur.getSite_id());

        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public List<InfoSecteur> lister(int ID) {
    List<InfoSecteur> infoSecteurs = new ArrayList<InfoSecteur>();
    Connection connexion = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet resultat = null;


    try {
        connexion = daoFactory.getConnection();
        ps = connexion.prepareStatement("SELECT name, description, site_id, sector_id FROM sector WHERE site_id=?");
        ps.setInt(1, ID);

        resultat = ps.executeQuery();



        // Récupération des données
        // On récupère un résultat brut de la bdd difficilement manipulable, donc on en extrait les donnés pour les stocker de manière plus propre et facile à manipuler grace au while
        while (resultat.next()) {
            // on récupère les entrées grace à la méthode getString ou getInt qui permettent de récupérer des données de types string ou int
            //resultat.getString => je m'attends à récupérer une chaine de caractère ou un nombre ou une date etc... puis on les tocke dans des objets de type string, int, etc...
            String name = resultat.getString("name");
            String description = resultat.getString("description");
            int site_id = resultat.getInt("site_id");
            int sector_id =resultat.getInt("sector_id");


            // On créé un java bean et on lui définit un nom et un prénom correspond à ceux que l'on vient de récupérer dans la bdd
            InfoSecteur infoSecteur = new InfoSecteur();
            infoSecteur.setName(name);
            infoSecteur.setDescription(description);
            infoSecteur.setSite_id(site_id);
            infoSecteur.setSector_id(sector_id);

            // on ajoute cet objet à un array (ou liste) grace à la méthode add. on ajout infoSecteur à infoSecteurs
            infoSecteurs.add(infoSecteur);
            // ensuite on boucle encore et encore grace au while jusqu'à tout récupérer
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } return infoSecteurs;

}
```